# How do I convert an integer to a float in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, integer, floating-point

I've got an *integer* (e.g. **12**), and I want to convert it to a *floating point number*, with a specified number of decimal places.

**Draft**

```
function intToFloat(num, decimal) { [code goes here] }
intToFloat(12, 1) // returns 12.0
intToFloat(12, 2) // returns 12.00
// and so on…
```

Answer (score 59, accepted):

What you have is already a floating point number, they're all 64-bit floating point numbers in JavaScript.

To get decimal places when rendering it (as a string, for output), use [`.toFixed()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed), like this:

```
function intToFloat(num, decPlaces) { return num.toFixed(decPlaces); }
```

[You can test it out here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/FC2QH/) (though I'd rename the function, given it's not an accurate description).

Comment: Nice! I – just like the previous commenter – never knew there is a bulit-in function for that! :) I think with such a short function, there is no need to declare another function for that, it would just slow down the script.

Comment: +1 Nice Realy i love it when i see many hidden features on javascript

Comment: Note, that toFixed returns String, not Float

Comment: @IvanKuckir Yes, but that's desirable in this case, as otherwise you couldn't differentiate between `12.0` and `12.00`.

Comment: toFixed works different in IE and other browsers.
In your approach the intToFloat(1.45, 1) in IE will return '1.5' 
Crome/FF will return '1.4'

Comment: In rare edge cases, the integer 1 behaves unexpectedly. Using `.toFixed(N)` on the integer equal to one fixed this for me. +1

Answer (score 3):

toFixed(x) isn't crossed browser solution.
Full solution is following:

```
function intToFloat(num, decPlaces) { return num + '.' + Array(decPlaces + 1).join('0'); }
```

Comment: `toFixed` works in the latest stable version of Chrome, Firefox, Internet Explorer and Opera. It also works in IE5/IE7/IE8/IE9/IE10 document modes (there's no IE6 document mode). The behavior is consistent.

Comment: toFixed works different in IE. When you run intToFloat(1.45, 1) IE will return '1.5' and Crome or FF will return '1.4'

Comment: I see. I didn't test that.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't need (or not sure about) fixed number of decimal places, you can just use

```
xAsString = (Number.isInteger(x)) ? (x + ".0") : (x.toString());
```

This is relevant in those contexts like, you have an `x` as `7.0` but `x.toString()` will give you `"7"` and you need the string as `"7.0"`. If the x happens to be a float value like say `7.1` or `7.233` then the string should also be `"7.1"` or `"7.233"` respectively.

Without using Number.isInteger() :

```
xAsString = (x % 1 === 0) ? (x + ".0") : (x.toString());
```